# How to use title with author name in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogs

Can I display post title with post author without using any file coding and any filter methods? My requirement is to display like `{Post Title} - {Post Author}` without using code files and without using hooks.

Comment: which page do you need to display?

Comment: i want post title with post author. But i do not want to code like get_the_title().'-'.get_the_author(). also i do not want to modify function via filters or any hooks.

Comment: So you want to change the way the page looks, without doing anything to change it? Erm...

Comment: Yes, without using theme code file and hooks also

Comment: you can't do this, the only way is 1)  from backend manual setup title , 2) you can use a plugin like https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-title, 3) customize the title and author tag  html on front end with position absolute/inline and then use yoast plugin  for <title> tag, yes extreme solution :)